# order queryset by total sum of prices in drf

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I use OrderingFilter, I have pizza model connected to pizzaprice model by many to many fields, when I order by desc or asc I don't get the expected result. How can I get queryset ordering by the sum of prices or first number in prices?

---

models.py

```
class Categorie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, default=[0])

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name

class PizzaPrice(models.Model):
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.price)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['price']

class PizzaSize(models.Model):
    size = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['size']

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.size)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    imageUrl = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Categorie, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.IntegerField(choices=PIZZA_RATING, default=1)
    sizes = models.ManyToManyField(PizzaSize, blank=True, default=[0])
    prices = models.ManyToManyField(PizzaPrice, blank=True, default=[0])


    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.name
```

---

serializer.py

```
class PizzaSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = serializers.CharField(source='category.name')
    sizes = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='size')
    prices = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='price')

    class Meta:
        model = Pizza
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

views.py

```
class PizzasList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Pizza.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PizzaSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]

    filterset_fields = ['category']
    ordering_fields = ['rating', 'name', 'prices']
```

---

[image: example of result: ordering by prices]

I tried many options but nothing helped

I started learning Django not very long ago and I don’t know much, I hope you can help with this question, thank you for your attention

[image: want to get queryset order by total sum of prices or first number in prices]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order your queryset by the sum of prices for each pizza, you can use Django's `Sum` function along with the `annotate` method in the queryset. Here's an example modification to your `PizzasList` view:

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

class PizzasList(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Pizza.objects.annotate(total_price=Sum('prices__price'))
    serializer_class = PizzaSerializer
    pagination_class = PageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, OrderingFilter]

    filterset_fields = ['category']
    ordering_fields = ['rating', 'name', 'total_price']
```

This modification uses `annotate` to add a new field `total_price` to each pizza in the queryset, representing the sum of prices associated with that pizza. Then, you can order by `total_price` in the ordering_fields. Note that this assumes you want to order in ascending order. If you want descending order, you can use `-total_price` instead.